# Filter array rows by matching one or more key-value pairs in associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-filter, array-intersect

Suppose,

```
$data = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1, 'assignment_id' => 1, 'grade' => 90),
   array('id' => 2, 'user_id' => 3, 'assignment_id' => 2, 'grade' => 85),
   array('id' => 3, 'user_id' => 5, 'assignment_id' => 5, 'grade' => 66),
);
```

Now I want to filter the rows like following:

```
$rules = array(
    'user_id' => 5,
    'assignment_id' => 5
);
```

This should return the row at `$data[2]`.

```
$rules = array(
    'user_id' => 3,
    'assignment_id' => 2,
    'grade' => 85
);
```

will return `$data[1]`.

Here order of `keys` may be different both in `$data` elements and `$rules`.

I tried with `array_intersect`, but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to return a list of of the elements in `$data` which match the filtering criteria, you can use a combination of `array_filter()` and `array_intersect_assoc()` to do the job:

```
// build an array of your filtering criteria
$filter_array = array(
   'user_id' => 3,
   'assignment_id' => 5
);

// filter the array
$filtered_array = array_filter($data, function ($val_array) use ($filter_array) {
    $intersection = array_intersect_assoc($val_array, $filter_array);
    return (count($intersection)) === count($filter_array);
});
```

Note that you need PHP >= 5.3.0 to utilize the anonymous function as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more modern and elegant approach.

Use arrow function syntax to allow `$rules` into the custom function's scope.  If after associatively filtering the rules array by each encountered row there are no remaining elements, then all rules were satisfied.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/etQPp))

```
$data = [
   ['id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1, 'assignment_id' => 1, 'grade' => 90],
   ['id' => 2, 'user_id' => 3, 'assignment_id' => 2, 'grade' => 85],
   ['id' => 3, 'user_id' => 5, 'assignment_id' => 5, 'grade' => 66],
];

$rules = ['user_id' => 3, 'assignment_id' => 2];

var_export(
    array_filter($data, fn($row) => !array_diff_assoc($rules, $row))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'user_id' => 3,
    'assignment_id' => 2,
    'grade' => 85,
  ),
)
```